# What are dart polymer transformer entry_points actually for?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Dart apps using polymer.dart have their pubspec.yaml file looking like this (from the [Polymer.dart Code Lab](https://www.dartlang.org/codelabs/polymer/)):

```yaml
name: polymer_and_dart
description: Sample app built with the polymer.dart package
environment:
  sdk: '>=1.2.0 <2.0.0'
dependencies:
  polymer: '>=0.12.0 <0.13.0'
dev_dependencies:
  unittest: '>=0.10.0 <0.11.0'
transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points:
    - web/begin/index.html
    - web/end/index.html
```

What do the `entry_points` actually mean? What does declaring an entry point actually do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the file where the transformer starts looking for polymer related files where it needs to do code generation and other modifications. The transformer follows HTML imports and Dart script tags.

An entry point is the main HTML files of a Polymer application (like `index.html`). Other files like custom elements are found automatically through imports.

For normal applications you might have only one entry point but for example a package of polymer elements like `core_elements` or `paper_elements` have a demo application page for each custom element in the package. Each such demo application is an entry point (normally in the `example` folder instead of `web`.

Comment: So not declaring any entry point would mean that the polymer stuff would not kick in at all?

Comment: Exactly, the transformer needs this setting.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Building part of Polymer.dart page](https://www.dartlang.org/polymer/#building):

> You can use `entry_points` to specify which pages under web the user can navigate to. (By default, all pages under web are entry points.)