# No elements registered in a while, but still waiting on 1 elements to be registered

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I'm trying out dart with polymer. I wanted to build a simple custom element. I based it on the custom element provided in the polymer example application in the dart editor.

Unfortunately I get the following error:

```
No elements registered in a while, but still waiting on 1 elements to be registered. Check that you have a class with an @CustomTag annotation for each of the following tags: 'send-card'
```

The code for the 'send-card' element looks as follows:

send_card.html

```
<!-- send card -->


<!-- import polymer-element's definition -->
<link rel="import" href="../../packages/polymer/polymer.html">

<link rel="import" href="../../packages/paper_elements/paper_input.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../packages/paper_elements/paper_fab.html">

<link rel="import" href="../../packages/core_elements/core_icons.html">

<polymer-element name="send-card">
  <template>
    <style>
      #input-wrapper {
        width: 500px;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 10px;
      }
      paper-input {
        color:#5677fc;
      }
      paper-fab {
        background: #5677fc;
        position: relative;
        right: -5px;
        bottom: -5px;
      }
    </style>

    <div id="input-wrapper">
      <paper-input multiline label="Your message"></paper-input>
      <paper-fab icon="add" on-click="{{sendMessage}}"></paper-fab>
    </div>

  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

send_card.dart

```
import 'package:paper_elements/paper_input.dart';
import 'package:paper_elements/paper_fab.dart';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

@CustomTag('send-card')
class SendCard extends PolymerElement {

  /// Constructor used to create instance of MainApp.
  SendCard.created() : super.created();

  void sendMessage(){}
}
```

It seems to me that everything is in place here. Can anybody explain that error?

PS: nothing shows up in the browser when I run the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include a script element to send_card.dart in the template:

send_card.html:

```
  <!-- ... -->
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="send_card.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this the last time when I forgot to add the entry page to the Polymer transformer configuration.

See also [What are dart polymer transformer entry_points actually for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26528612/what-are-dart-polymer-transformer-entry-points-actually-for)